# isAuthenticated is undefined react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

isAuthenticated is undefined when i run this code. how can is use isAuthenticated with `mapStateProps`. if i am use Token `(Token '5302f4340a76cd80a855286c6d9e0e48d2f519cb'} like this then it's working fine but i want Authorized it with props.isAuthenticated anybody know how can i solve this issue?

authAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
    import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

    export const authStart = () => {
        return {
            type: actionTypes.AUTH_START
        }
    }

    export const authSuccess = token => {
        return {
            type: actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
            token: token
        }
    }

    export const authFail = error => {
        return {
            type: actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL,
            error: error
        }
    }

    export const logout = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        return {
            type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT
        };
    }



    export const authLogin = (userData) => {
        return dispatch => {
            dispatch(authStart());
            axios.post('http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/', userData)
                .then(res => {
                    const token = res.data.key;
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                    dispatch(authSuccess(token));
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    dispatch(authFail(err))
                })
        }
    }
```

authReducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';
    import { updateObject } from '../utility';

    const initialState = {
        isAuthenticated: null,
        token: null,
        error: null,
        loading: false
    }

    const authStart = (state, action) => {
        return updateObject(state, {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            error: null,
            loading: true
        });
    }

    const authSuccess = (state, action) => {
        return updateObject(state, {
            isAuthenticated: true,
            token: action.token,
            error: null,
            loading: false
        });
    }

    const authFail = (state, action) => {
        return updateObject(state, {
            error: action.error,
            loading: false
        });
    }

    const authLogout = (state, action) => {
        return updateObject(state, {
            token: null
        });
    }

    export default function (state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case actionTypes.AUTH_START: return authStart(state, action);
            case actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS: return authSuccess(state, action);
            case actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL: return authFail(state, action);
            case actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT: return authLogout(state, action);
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import auth from './authReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    auth: auth
});
```

articleList.js

```
const NewsList = (props) => {
    // ...
   const fetchItems = async () => {
                try {
                    const config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        Authorization: `Token ${props.isAuthenticated}`
                    }
                }
                    const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/`, config);
                    setItems(res.data)
                    setLoading(false);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(` Axios request failed: ${err}`);
                }
            }
            fetchItems()
        })
        }, [items]);
    // ...
 }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.token
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewsList)
```

Comment: where is your reducers and types sir?

Comment: It's difficult to say by just looking at this code

Comment: can you do a console.log(state.auth); in the mapStateToProps?

Comment: hmmmm, import auth from './auth' ? is it correct? can i see your auth.js ? or maybe you are trying to import authReduer ? then you should import your file correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the (or a) problem if the reducer is actually named authReducer.js

Comment: this problems are so annoying, trying hours and then you realize that the problem was the naming @PaulW

Comment: Yeah, people are not usually looking for such an obvious mistake, and often don't find those types of bugs until they walk away for a while. Good eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug your code. Start by connecting the dots: The output tells you that `props.isAuthenticated` is `undefined`. You pass this in from `state.auth.token` in `mapStateToProps()`:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.token
    }
}
```

So `state.auth.token` must be undefined also. That's as far as I can get from what you have shown me. You will need to debug further to figure out why. You can use the React Dev Tools to inspect props of your components. You can use Redux Dev Tools to inspect and manipulate the redux state. Check what the value of `auth.token` is in state. Look where it is supposed to be set and find out why it isn't getting set to a valid value.

Be sure to check [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.